# Как на FastReport можно сделать гистограмму с группировкой

Tags: delphi, vcl, fastreport, teechart

Возможно ли сделать что-то похожее на этот рисунок в FastReport VCL, но когда есть только один датасет, в котором есть поля «country», «year» и «value»? [image: Пример того, что должно получиться]
В обычном редакторе форм это делается через DBCrossTabSource, но как получить такое в FastReport? Или как-то возможно добавить внешний ChartSeries в имеющийся frxChartView?